# Find list of nodes in hadoop cluster from outside of the cluster

Tags: java, hadoop

I would like to run the equivalent of:

```
hadoop dfsadmin -report
```

From a a machine that is not a node in the hadoop cluster. Is this possible? If so, is there a way to do this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely call this from any machine where Hadoop libraries are in the classpath of your calling program.

final Configuration conf = new Configuration();
 conf.set("fs.defaultFS", name node host:port);

final DFSAdmin admin = new DFSAdmin(conf);
 admin.report();

This will print the output to the console.